# Unique constraint across collections on nodes

Tags: neo4j

If we want to enforce a constraint that each user will have an unique email associated with them, we could write:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (X:User) ASSERT X.email IS UNIQUE
```

Let us consider a case where email addresses are collections, but we still need to have an uniqueness constraint, such that an email address appears only once across the `User.username` collection, for all users. In other words, the following should never happen:

```
(a:User {username: "user1234", email: ["foo@bar.com", "foo2@bar.com"])
(b:User {username: "someperson", email: ["foo@bar.com", "me@someperson.com"])
```

since `foo@bar.com` appears across both `a.email` and `b.email`.

Is there a way to do this in Neo4j and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must you store email addresses in a collection on the User node? Would it make more sense to use :EmailAddress nodes with a unique constraint on an email property? Users can have [:HasEmail] relationships to :EmailAddress nodes, that will give you your one-to-many relationships similar to collections.

The tricky part is then making sure that email saving/creating/changing logic doesn't accidentally link multiple users to a single EmailAddress node. You'll probably want to use CREATE explicitly when creating the EmailAddress node (which may fail because of the unique property constraint) instead of MERGE so it doesn't match on an already created email address.